# git merge force mergetool

Tags: git, git-merge

**Simple setup**: two branches with different contents of a file

```
A         - HEAD, MASTER
 \- B     - BRANCH_B
```

**What I need**: a new commit where I manually choose the contents of the file from the two branches (something like mergetool)

```
A - - - C   - HEAD, MASTER
 \- B -/    - BRANCH_B
```

---

I have experience only with basic workflow with branches and I couldn't manage to do this at all.
Everything I tried ended with the file with the contents from commit B:

```
git merge --no-ff B
git merge --no-ff B -X ours
git cherry-pick B
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
git cherry-pick -n commitId
```

That cherry-picks your commits and does not commit it to your branch which means that you can modify the changes.

Comment: This requires difftool and manual copy/pasting. I am still waiting for a solution with mergetool and that makes both A and B parents of C. It is a working solution though so thank you.